# populate a combobox using a selection in another combobox from excel sheet

Tags: vb.net

Hi  i need to populate a combobox using the selected value in another combo. The coding that i use doesn't produce the required output.  i have an excel sheet with columns called "BaseStation" & "SectorID". Combobox2 must display the related sector id with respect to the selected BaseStation

Given below is the error that  i get:
"Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'BaseStation='."

Please help. the coding given below:

```
    Private Sub ComboBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.TextChanged
    Using cn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection With _
            { _
                .ConnectionString = _
                <S>
    provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;
    Data Source=C:\WalkAir Customers.xls;
    Extended Properties="Excel 8.0; HDR=Yes;"
</S>.Value _
            }
        Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
        Dim dr As System.Data.IDataReader

        cn.Open()

        cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand()
        cmd.Connection = cn
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$] WHERE BaseStation=" & ComboBox1.Text

        Dim dtData As New DataTable
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        dtData.Load(dr)
        dtData.Columns("SectorID").ColumnMapping = MappingType.Hidden

        bsCustomers.DataSource = dtData
    End Using

    ComboBox2.DisplayMember = "SectorID"
    ComboBox2.DataSource = bsCustomers
End Sub
```

Comment: And what output do you get, and what would you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting single quotes around the BaseStation parameter:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$] WHERE BaseStation='" & ComboBox1.Text & "'"
```